# Swift Firebase Query Mid Section of Nodes Without Unique Child Value

Tags: swift, firebase

I have autoid keys for messages under a node for each user that looks like

```
user1: {
    user2: {
      -MEt4K5xhsYL33anhXpP: 1
      -MEt8BLP2yMEUMPbG2zV: 1
      ...(10 more keys)...
      -MF-Grpl8Jchxpbn2mxH: 1
      -MF-OUjWXsFh7lBPosMf: 1
    }
}
```

I was following a tutorial that was setting the default value to 1. I'm realizing now this may be an issue. Is there a way to query for the keys between "-MEt8BLP2yMEUMPbG2zV" and "-MF-Grpl8Jchxpbn2mxH" such that I get the 10 keys between them? I tried querying like this but it didn't work.

Edit: To clarify I only know the second key e.g. "-MF-Grpl8Jchxpbn2mxH"

```
ref.queryEnding(beforeValue: 1, childKey: "-MF-Grpl8Jchxpbn2mxH").queryLimitedToLast(10).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
```

[query mid-section of firebase database in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37086713/query-mid-section-of-firebase-database-in-swift)

I've looked at this post that had a similar question. They resolved by ordering by a timestamp, but I'm wondering if there is a way to do so with my current implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You're not ordering the `ref` on anything, which means that it defaults to interpreting your `beforeValue` as a key.

What you want is:

```
var ref = Database.database().reference("user1/user2")

ref.queryOrderedByKey()
   .queryStarting(atValue: 1, childKey: "-MEt8BLP2yMEUMPbG2zV")
   .queryEnding(atValue: 1, childKey: "-MF-Grpl8Jchxpbn2mxH")
   ...
```

Since you know the start and end key, there's no need to also specify a limit, although you can do so if you want.

Comment: I only know the second key. I'm using this for a chat feature and trying to get a number of message ids each time the user scrolls up to load more e.g. the 10 above "-MF-Grpl8Jchxpbn2mxH"

Comment: Thanks though I needed to order by key

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this. I thought atValue needed to be 1 but it should be the message id and I needed to orderByKey.

```
ref.queryOrderedByKey().queryEnding(atValue: "-MF-Grpl8Jchxpbn2mxH").queryLimited(toLast: 10)
```